# Does upgrading a single connector requires restart of the worker?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka Connect cluster with several connectors, say C1 and C2, and I have a worker running 2 tasks, one with connector C1 and one with connector C2. 
I've updated the code for connector C1 and replaced the jar in plugins directory, is it enough to restart the task which runs C1 or I'll need to restart the worker (and therfore all tasks it runs will be restarted)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Kafka Connect to pick up a changed JAR, you'll need to restart the worker itself. A `Task` is just a logical execution unit within the Worker itself.

More info:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/design.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html